# Tricky AC power Question

Tags: ac, circuits

Greetings all,
             Just to be clear, I am not asking anyone to do my homework. I am simply asking for guidance and or to clarify any conceptual errors I am making. For the following question, I can get the length of the impedance of the factory load by Vrms/Irms. And I can write that as \$ 7.36864\cos\theta + j7.3684\sin{\theta} \$. I also know that the total impedance the source sees has a length of 7.3684 because of Ohms law. So I had an equation where I had the real parts and imaginary parts, square them and it must equal 7.3684. and I know have the angle of the impedance for the factory load, so I know have the imaginary and real part of the load. But I am uncertain where to go from here. Work is attached below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wha site and program / website did your professor / faculty / TA use to provide you with these questions?

Comment: The load is capacitive so how come you got a complex impedance for the load based on 140 V and 19 A. I don't follow what you are doing. In other words where is the factory load angle specified?